# capture websocket request in cypress

Tags: websocket, cypress, cypress-intercept

I'm trying to capture all the requests that occur during the test.
My application uses WebSocket and with the intercept command I can't catch wss requests.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: BurpSuite has what you're looking for.You can even modify websocket data, intercept it, etc.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think web sockets can be caught directly by the intercept command.

One approach is to observe the results of ws communication, as shown here [Testing a websocket application with Cypress](https://filiphric.com/testing-websocket-application-with-cypress) between two instance of Cypress runner.

If your app talks between app and server, then start the server in `/cypress/plugins/index.js` and use `cy.task()` to get the server end of the communication.

---

There is also a library [cypress-websocket-testing](https://github.com/lensesio/cypress-websocket-testing) which uses rxjs, which is quite powerful but takes some getting used to.

```js
cy.streamRequest(config, options).then(results => {
        expect(results).to.not.be.undefined;
})
// When in need of a bit more flexibility
cy.stream(config).then(subject => {
      subject
        .pipe(
          takeUntil(timer(1000)),
          reduce((acc , val) => acc.concat([val]), [])
        )
        .subscribe({
          next: (results) => {
            expect(results).to.not.be.undefined;
          },
          error: (err) => {},
          complete: done
        });
    });
```

Comment: In 2024 is this still the best option to do websocket tests in cypress?

Comment: The best option I found was to capture the har file while running the test.  
This file will contain all the useful information about the wss requests. I recommend using this plugin from cypress: https://github.com/NeuraLegion/cypress-har-generator

Answer (score -1):

Not supported in Cypress as of now only xhr requests are supported by cy.intercept, you need to create wesbsocket server and listen at a port and it needed to be started in another process and then using fixtures send the required response data