# testing websocket messages with Cypress

Tags: websocket, cypress

I need to test WS messages with specific text are received/send from/to a 3rd party provider.

for example: in https://websocketstest.com/ I need to validate there is a time message received.
[image]

I don't need to mock the messages, I don't need to establish connection through Cypress. Just check the messages. I tried to setup this lib cypress-websocket-testing as set in their example, but to no avail.
does anyone have successfully tested such scenarios? Cypress are claiming they support WS, but have literally 0 documentation about it.

Comment: please take a look into: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71705986/capture-websocket-request-in-cypress

Comment: ***To no avail*** - what did you try, can you give an example of a failed test?

Comment: @Dxg125, yes, i tried the lib linked in this thread.
basically  copied the examples here https://github.com/lensesio/cypress-websocket-testing/blob/master/examples/cypress/integration/examples/stream.spec.ts and changed the wss url, i was hoping the first test will pass and go from there. but all my tests are failing because of 'WebSocket connection to 'wss://websocketstest.com/' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.' in dev console

Comment: Hey, did you consider debugging why the request (as per screenshot) is getting blocked by the client? Do you maybe have some .htaccess / server config files that restrict WSS? Also the warning right before the error is suspect, as maybe some CORS or else is blocking.